Automating User Login on Emirates.com with Cypress: Issue with Continuous Loading After Adding Credentials
I am trying to automate user login on the Emirates.com website using the Cypress automation tool, but I’m encountering an issue. After entering the credentials and clicking login button, the page continues to load indefinitely.
However, when I perform the same actions using Selenium, the login process completes successfully.
Here is a summary of what I have done so far:
Code:
describe('Emirates.com Login', () => {
  it('should log in successfully', () => {
    cy.visit('https://www.emirates.com');

    cy.get('input#username').type('your-username');
    cy.get('input#password').type('your-password');
    
    cy.get('button[type="submit"]').click();

    // Wait for the login to complete
    cy.wait(10000); // Adjust based on actual loading time

    // Check if login was successful
    cy.url().should('include', '/dashboard'); 

  });
});

What I Have Tried:

Adjusting Wait Times.
Checking for Elements to ensure the elements are correctly targeted.
Running Cypress in Different Browsers but the issue remains.
Comparing with Selenium: The same test works with Selenium without any issues.
Setting the browser user agent
How to load a Salesforce page with Cypress

Questions:

Could Emirates.com be blocking automated logins?: Is it possible that the site has mechanisms in place to detect and block automated tools like Cypress? Are there specific anti-bot measures that could be interfering?
Are there known compatibility issues with Cypress and Emirates.com?
Is there something I might have missed in my Cypress configuration?


Cypress uses an iframe to contains the app, and this comes with a bunch of complexities that can sometimes fall over with enterprise federated login systems. It is also possible they are actively blocking automation. Cypress attempts to circumvent that with modifyObstructiveCode option. This is on by default. However there is also experimentalModifyObstructiveThirdPartyCode, which has to be manually turned on in cypress config. Worth a try?
